# Encrypt/DecryptByPassphrase returning different results in different IDEs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to be able to encrypt and decrypt without adding additional tables, modifying tables, or modifying any certificates in the database. I could add a certificates but I'm not certain how those work just yet. I've got a solution that I'm reasonable certain will work.

The problem is I wrote the solution in Jetbrains Rider which has SQL DB management capabilities. My SQL is not strong and its got wonderful code completion and suggestions to help guide me along. When I take it into the lab to work with I'm using SQL Management Studio. I've confirmed it doesn't work in Management Studio, neither at my desk or on the lab. It only works in Rider.

The query I'm running:

```
USE WorkDemo

DECLARE @passphrase varchar(30) = 'BarrelBlast3437'
DECLARE @entryValue varchar(50) = 'KingKrab'
DECLARE @encryptedValue varchar(250) = CAST(ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@passphrase, @entryValue) As VARCHAR(250))
DECLARE @decryptedValue varchar(250) = DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@passphrase, @encryptedValue)

--To reset the value each test so its not double encrypted
Update MyTable
SET Data = @entryValue
WHERE ID = 'Credentials'

PRINT @encryptedValue --This Returns the Encrypted Value

PRINT @decryptedValue

Update MyTable
SET Data = @encryptedValue
WHERE ID = 'Credentials'

SELECT DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('BarrelBlast3437', Data)
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID = 'Credentials'
GO
```

After encrypting, updating the table with the value, then selecting that value I get:

Results in SQL Management Studio: '0x4B696E674B726162'

Results in Rider: 'KingKrab'

[image: This should provide most of what you need to know]

Thanks in advance for everyone's efforts to assist me! I've been stuck on this for about a day but I will update here in the comments as I find more info.

Comment: `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` gives a `VARBINARY` which is not necessarily directly convertible to a `VARCHAR` in any way that works. Use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(250), ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@passphrase, @entryValue), 1)` to get a hexstring (and `DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@passphrase, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @encryptedValue, 1))`) to convert it back.

Comment: [2019-10-24 09:37:44] [S0005][8114] Error converting data type varchar to varbinary.

I get this error when attempting to convert it back using the DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE statement you provided. The error message is vague.

[Here's an image of the issue](https://ibb.co/4P7MCbs) I used print statements to divine the point of failure.

Comment: I had made the possibly unwarranted assumption that the `Data` column in your table was also a `VARCHAR`, but if it's a `VARBINARY`, no converting is needed at all. Just store the result of `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` directly. Conversion would only be necessary for display purposes (e.g. `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 0x4B696E674B726162)`, `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(...)) FROM [Table]`.

Comment: I apologize. I didn't give enough context. It is a varbinary(3000) column. That's something I can't change either. I changed the 1 to a 0 for what I believe is called the style guide parameter on the decrypt and [I'm getting some interesting albeit confusing results](https://ibb.co/TvXdZW4). It appears to convert and deconvert without issue but when I try to SELECT the value it returns null.

Comment: The third parameter to `CONVERT` is for hexstrings. The third parameter to `ENCRYPT`/`DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` is a flag that indicates if an authenticator (salt) should be added. Don't use that -- if you do, the parameter must be the same on both the `ENCRYPT` and the `DECRYPT`.

Comment: So I was able to select the appropriate value from a variable. The issue is I'm executing it from an API which, for security reasons, will only allow me to execute a single statement. So one for the encryption. Which appears to be working. The one I wrote for pulling the value works when I say `DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('BarrelBlast3437', (SELECT Data FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 'Credentials'))`. If I assign this to a variable and select that variable I get the decrypted response. [If I try to just select the statement above it I get what I believe is the hexstring value.](https://ibb.co/z7nLjSL)

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('BarrelBlast3437', Data)) FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 'Credentials'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE WorkDemo

--To reset the value each test so its not double encrypted
Update MyTable
SET Data = 'DonkeyKong'
WHERE ID = 'Credentials'

--Assign the converted value to the appropriate record.
Update MyTable
SET Data = CONVERT(VARCHAR(250), ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('BarrelBlast3437', 'DonkeyKong'), 0)
WHERE ID = 'Credentials'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(250), DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('BarrelBlast3437', Data)) FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 'Credentials'

SELECT ID, Data As 'Encrypted Data' FROM MyTable

GO

================

Courtesy of Joroen Mostert. Thanks for all your assistance with this one!